# Evaluating the integral $\int_0^{\pi/4}\sqrt{1-16\sin^2(x)}\mathop{}\!\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

How can we evaluate this integral?
$$\int_\limits{0}^{\pi/4}\sqrt{1-16\sin^2(x)}\mathop{}\!\mathrm dx$$
I tried a substitution 
$$u=4\sin x,\quad \mathrm dx=\frac{\mathrm du}{\sqrt{16-u^2}}$$
hence the integration will be

$$\int_\limits{u=0}^{u=2\sqrt{2}}\frac{\sqrt{1-u^2}}{\sqrt{16-u^2}}\mathop{}\!\mathrm du$$
But I could not complete the solution using this substitution.

Comment: Accordingly, [this cannot be solved in terms of elementary functions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%5Csqrt%7B(1-16%5Csin%5E2(x))%7Ddx). In other words, there is no closed form solution and you must resort to [numerical integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) over a given interval.

Comment: You have an elliptic integral.  Furthermore, at $x = \frac {\pi}{4}$ the integrand is complex.

Comment: u = 2.sin x is a nice substitution but results in complex numbers.

Comment: You're taking the square root of negative numbers in the integral. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\,\sqrt{\,{1 - 16\sin^{2}\left(\, x\,\right)}\,}\,\,\mathrm{d}x & =
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\,\sqrt{\,{1 - 4^{2}\sin^{2}\left(\, x\,\right)}\,}\,\,\mathrm{d}x
\\[5mm] & =
\bbox[10px,#ffd,border:1px groove navy]{\mathrm{E}\left(\,{{\pi \over 4},4}\,\right)}
\end{align}

> $\displaystyle\mathrm{E}$ is a
>   [Legendre Integral](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.2.E5).

Comment: @Clayton I don't think so. Maybe, that's ONE of the reasons people define a new "special function".

Comment: Thanks, Felix!${}$